# Unable to Insert Select statement with php mysql prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, insert-select

Can anyone help me with the mysql query. I am trying to insert multiple rows using an insert select statement.

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO order_processing_info (order_id, cart_item_id, item_id, price, quantity) VALUES (?, (SELECT s.cart_item_id, i.item_id, i.price, s.quantity FROM inventory_info AS i, cart_info AS s  WHERE i.item_id=s.item_id AND s.user_id = ?))")) {
                    $insert_stmt->bind_param('ss', $order_id, $user_id);
```

I think the problem is because i want same order_id for all insert here, although i am not sure.

Previously i tried to unsuccessfully run it in a select statement block.

```
if ($select_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT i.item_id, i.price, s.quantity, s.cart_item_id FROM inventory_info AS i, shopping_cart_info AS s  WHERE i.item_id=s.item_id AND s.user_id = ?")) {
        $select_stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
        $select_stmt->execute();
        $select_stmt->bind_result($item_id, $price, $quantity, $cart_item_id);

        while ($select_stmt->fetch()) {

            if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO order_processing_info (order_id, cart_item_id, item_id, price, quantity) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
                $insert_stmt->bind_param('sssss', $order_id, $cart_item_id, $item_id, $price, $quantity);
                // Execute the prepared query.
                if (!$insert_stmt->execute()) {
                    header('Location: ../error.php?err=INSERT failure: INSERT');
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
        $select_stmt->close();
    }
```

I have looked it up a lot on stackoverflow, but i guess i am not that proficient in database queries, so i would appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use an "INSERT INTO SELECT" query (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp), only one paramemter needs to be bound then, the user ID. It'll also save on the overhead of the query in the loop

Comment: Thanks i was able to work it out by putting insert statement in a loop of select statements fetch result. Thanks for the help!